# How to get key value pair if we have same id and multiple.values

Tags: mysql

I have an issue 
My table look like this:

```
Id  meta key  meta value
1      'a'       12
1      'b'       14
1      'c'       15
```

Now i have to get the meta value of a
and meta value of b through a mysql query, kindly guide me.

Comment: Do you mean something like:

SELECT meta_value FROM table WHERE meta_key = 'a' OR meta_key = 'b';

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
SELECT meta_value FROM table WHERE meta_key = 'a' OR meta_key = 'b';
```

Another thing, is **Id** the table's primary key? Why are those three data have the same id that equals to 1?